# Как отключить редирект у пользователей?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Установил через ISP редирект на другой сайт. После нужда в этом отпала. Я удалил редирект. Но хром продолжает его делать. Я так понимаю он кэширует эти данные. У себя в браузере улалил кэш. Но сомневаюсь, что пользователи будут это делать. Как можно на стороне сервера удалить у них этот кэш?

Comment: Думаю никак если при установке кэша вы не проставили время его истечения.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то "редирект" хранится в кеше. Значит, можно сделать проверку на наличие этой шняги в кеше.. Если да -> удалить и обновить стр, если нет -> хорошо. И, соответственно, никого заставлять не нужно будет о.о